# Examples of hyperbolic groups that have boundary homeomorphic to $S^2$?

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces, hyperbolic-groups

I am working on understanding Cannon's Conjecture which is the following:

Suppose that $G$ is an infinite, finitely presented group whose Cayley graph is Gromov-hyperbolic and whose space at infinity is the 2-sphere $S^2$. Then $G$ is a Kleinian group.

I am just trying to gather examples of groups that have such a boundary.

Thanks!

Comment: I could write an answer later but if you want explicit examples you can play around with SnapPy, which is a program to help study 3-manifolds, to get fundamental groups of closed hyperbolic 3-manifolds (which are Kleinian). You can get presentations and maybe matrix representations (I would have to check)

Comment: @PaulPlummer Thanks for the tip. I installed SnapPy, and I'm figuring out how to play around with it. I would appreciate an answer from you later when you get the chance!

Comment: @JCAA I understand that Kleinian groups mean discrete subgroups of isometries of $H^3$. Some of them are hyperbolic but not cocompact; their boundary is then not a 2-sphere (this includes surface groups). Conjecturally, modulo finite kernel, cocompact lattices in $Isom(H^3)$ are exactly the only examples of hyperbolic groups with boundary homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking at fundamental groups of closed hyperbolic three-manifolds, which is the torsion free case of the Cannon conjecture. Note that hyperbolic three space, $\mathbb{H}^3$, has boundary $S^2$. By [Švarc–Milnor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0varc%E2%80%93Milnor_lemma) the fundamental groups of closed hyperbolic three-manifolds are quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{H}^3$ therefore have the same boundary.

---

#### Mapping torus construction

One way to produce such manifolds, and their fundamental groups, is through the mapping torus construction. Let $S$ be a closed surface of genus greater than one and $f:S \to S$ a homeomorphism. You can construct a three manifold
$$M=\frac{S \times [0,1]}{(x,0)\sim(f(x),1)}.$$
This construction, by a theorem of Thurston, gives a hyperbolic manifold exactly when $f$, up to isotopy, is a [psuedo-Anosov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Anosov_map). Pseudo-Anosov is equivalent to any power of $f$ not fixing the isotopy class of essential simple closed curves on the surface.
You can describe $\pi_1(M)$ explicitly by an [HNN extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension) in a similar way you use the Seifert–van Kampen theorem theorem to describe amalgamated products. *A Primer on Mapping Class Groups* by Farb and Margalit explains some ways to construct pseudo-Anosov's.

Fairly recently [the virtually fibered conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtually_fibered_conjecture) was proved. Amazingly, the theorem proves all closed hyperbolic three manifolds have a finite cover of the above form. An important part of the proof is a result by Kahn and Marcovic which shows that hyperbolic three-manifold groups have "lots of" quasi-isometrically embedded surface subgroups (a strengthening of the [surface subgroup conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_subgroup_conjecture)). Marcovic has put out a [criterion based off this idea](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5747). Basically, under the conditions of the Cannon conjecture, if all such groups have "enough" quasi-isometrically embedded surface subgroups the Cannon conjecture is true. Note that there is a big open question asking if all one ended hyperbolic groups contain surface subgroups (or even the stronger question of quasi-isometrically embedded surface subgroups).

---

#### Using computers (SnapPy)

You can also use programs which have been created to study three manifolds. The one you should definitely know about is SnapPea/[SnapPy](https://snappy.math.uic.edu/#). Here is an example in SnapPy:

Do `M = Manifold('m004')`, to name the manifold `m004` `M`, then type `M.browse()` which will give a bunch of information in a new window, including the fundamental group.
This manifold is not closed but you can do a [Dehn filling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_surgery). In SnapPy you can do this in the browse window or in the command line. For example one Dehn filling example is `M.dehn_fill( (4,3) )`. When you have a hyperbolic manifold `M` you can type `G=M.fundamental_group()` to get a presentation(or view it in the browse window). In the specific example above we get:

```
Generators:
   a,b
Relators:
   aBAbaabAB
   abbaBAbABabbbaBAbAB
```

If you want matrices from that presentation you can type `G.SL2C( 'x' )` where `x` is a word in your presentation. This will get into floating point/approximation errors.

There are [tutorials](https://snappy.math.uic.edu/tutorial.html) on SnapPy website. Here is one [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezo19L-JTTI) which explains a bit and also explains a cool way to construct manifolds in SnapPy by just drawing knots or links (then you can fill if you want closed).

There is a program [Twister](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgar/Maths/twister.html) which can work with SnapPy and produce manifolds from the mapping torus perspective.

Just because it is cool and I want to show it off, here is an example using the drawing tool. Typing `N = Manifold()` opens up the drawing screen. Now draw a knot or a link. Under tools click send to SnapPy. Here is my example:

[image]

We will now fill the knot to get a closed manifold(most of the time hyperbolic). My arbitrary choice is `N.dehn_fill( '(3,2)' )`. You can use `N.browse()` or `N.fundamental_group()` to view the fundamental group and in this case we have:

```
Generators:
   a,b
Relators:
   aBAbabAbaBABaBABabAbabABaBABaBAbabAbabABaBABabAbabAbaBABaBAbabAbabABaBABaaBABaBAbabAbabABaBABabAbabAbaBABaBAbabAbabABaBAB
   aBABabAbabAbaBABaBAbabAbabABaBABabaBABaBAbabAbabABaBABabAbabAbaBABaBAbbbABaBABabAbabAbaBABaBAbabAbabABaBABabaBABaBAbabAbabABaBABabAbabAbaBABaBAbbAB
```

Good luck getting any understanding of the Cannon conjecture from that!