# Presentation for a hyperbolic group with 2-sphere boundary.

Tags: geometric-topology, fundamental-groups, mobius-transformation, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

I am looking for examples of hyperbolic groups that have boundary homeomorphic to the 2-sphere, $S^2$. I would like an explicit presentation of such a group so that I can draw its Cayley graph and play around with it. I know some examples are fundamental groups of hyperbolic 3-manifolds and hyperbolic Coxeter groups, but it is quite difficult to find explicit presentations.

If someone could also explain how to prove that its boundary is in fact the 2-sphere, that would be quite helpful. Yes, this is related to Cannon's Conjecture.

Comment: You have a [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763711/examples-of-hyperbolic-groups-that-have-boundary-homeomorphic-to-s2) you asked before, which gives ways to find and get presentations of such groups(and gives an explicit example). I gave an example presentation, and could give one using the fibered construction/HNN extension as that is pretty explicit.

Comment: The hard part of Cannon's conjecture is that we don't know how to construct counter examples or show that the boundary information is all that you need to determine that the group is Kleinian. Looking at known examples is basically just looking at $\mathbb{H}^3$, geometrically.

Comment: Also, Thurston's three manifold notes talk about hyperbolic Dehn surgery and discusses in some detail the complement of the figure eight knot (knot groups explicit calculable presentation) and which fillings give closed hyperbolic 3 manifolds which you can compute by hand presentation using Seifert-van Kampen or use SnapPy as I suggest in my previous answer.

Comment: To say more precisely what's essentially been said (a) If a group discrete $G$ admits a geometric (= isometric proper cocompact) action on $\mathbb{H}^3_\mathbf{R}$, or equivalently if it has a finite normal subgroup $W$ such that $G/W$ is isomorphic to a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{PO}(3,1)$, then $G$ is hyperbolic and its boundary is a topological 2-sphere. [If so $W$ is uniquely characterized as the largest finite normal subgroup of $G$.] (b) Cannon's conjecture is that these are the only examples.

Comment: You mention hyperbolic Coxeter groups, but don't these provide explicit (and understandable) presentations?

Comment: Read e.g Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Dynkin_diagram#Hyperbolic_Coxeter_groups with explicit examples of Coxeter diagrams for cocompact hyperbolic groups acting on hyperbolic 3-space. From these diagrams it is easy to read off presentations.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to explicitly draw the Cayley graph is to look at fundamental domains and take the dual graph.

Take a right-angled dodecahedron; you can think of its dual as a vertex with 12 edges going out. Attach a new right-angled dodecahedron to each of those faces. So far the graph we have is (part of) a valence-12 tree.

In the next step, we add on more right-angled dodecahedra, but now we 'complete the right-angles', so a single fundamental domain gets attached to two adjacent faces at once. This creates four-cycles in the graph. Continuing on in this way will easily get you the Cayley graph. This is by far the simplest hyperbolic Cayley graph with a 2-sphere boundary that I know of.